# SharePoint Designer 2010 (SPD) + Windows Vista + UAC = Requires Administrator?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to run SharePoint Designer 2010 on a Windows Vista machine where I am NOT an administrator. I get prompted for UAC requiring me to enter administrator credentials. Does SharePoint Designer 2010 require administrator permissions to run? If so, what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Does it need to do this every time, even after you allow it admin rights the first time?

Comment: Well, I cannot give it admin credentials because I don't have any. That is, it is asking for Admin Credentials, I don't have any, so therefore it never allows me "the first time".  So I enter MY credentials (which are the only credentials I have) it continuously re-prompts me (again, because I am NOT an Admin).

Comment: I suspect we'd have to do something via Group Policy to make an exception for SharePoint Designer to NOT be controlled via UAC.  Is this possible?  Is this what I must do if I want to let users in the company use the tool?

Comment: If SPD has not been run before, it may need to 'finish installing', as many applications do, to configure themselves for the environment. Find out if you can get it running for the first time with UAC, then try thereafter.

Comment: Ahh.  So the .exe downloaded online is just an "installer".  So, to deploy to the masses, we'd need either have the installation "pushed" to appropriate user machines and/or put something in place that allows the "installer" .exe to run.